# Found unsigned entry in resource

Tags: java, jar, jnlp, java-web-start

i have the following JNLP file:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://****:****" href="tcm2012.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>TCM 2012</title>
    <vendor>Drift og Performance, *** Servicecenter</vendor>
    <homepage href="http://******"/>
    <description/>
  </information>
  <security>
    <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="tcm2012.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.****.kundeservice.TCMApplication"/>
</jnlp>
```

Now when i try to run in from the web i get the following error:

```
Found unsigned entry in resource
```

With the following exepction

```
com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://*****:****/tcm2012.jar
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You need your jars to be signed for JNLP.

Comment: @Makky My jar is signed

Comment: ok ..are they still valid though?

Comment: They should be the program worked a few weeks ago

Comment: What if their validity was valid until yesterday?

Comment: @Makky wouldnt the rest of my programs that have been signed the same way also stop working?

Comment: Yes. It would stop working.

Comment: This also check all the depedant jars as well .

Comment: Examine carefully the output of `jarsigner -verify tcm2012.jar` using a 1.7.0_25+ (ideally) SDK.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440841/jre-1-7u45-unable-to-load-an-applet-containing-some-unsigned-entries

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This worked for me:

Go the Control Panel/Java.

Then click on “Settings” button and activate the option “Keep temporary files on my computer.”

It’s weird, but it worked!

Comment: Also it's worth to examine the MANIFEST.MF of the (unsigned) jar mentioned in the JarSigningException. This phenomenon seems to be related to package version information entries (e.g. Name: com.package.foo) present in the manifest of the unsigned jar. See also: http://web.archive.org/web/20140301230037/http://blog.atlashost.eu:80/post/found-unsigned-entry-in-resource-java-web-start.html

Comment: Actually, there's a fresher link to the above content: https://nowaker.net/post/found-unsigned-entry-in-resource-java-web-start.html (Looks like the author, Damian Nowak moved his blog to his own domain since 2014.)

Answer (score 10):

The problem can also occur with older Java Versions if you sign with a newer Java versions.

- Sign with 1.8u74 and older works with all versions
- Sign with 1.8u101 and newer works with 1.7u80 and newer but not with older versions on the client.

There seems a incompatible change in the sign algorithm.

Comment: I installed "Java SE Runtime Environment 8u74" (jre-8u74-windows-i586.exe) from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase8-archive-downloads.html just as you directed. It solved the above problem. Many thanks, Horcrux7.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with my applications.

I' ve a java swing application deployed with javaws:

- when I run the application using JRE 1.6 I get the exception
- when I run the application using JRE 1.7 and JRE 1.8 it works

I checked all the jar, MANIFEST.MF etc. and all was fine.
Finally I discovered that I've used a new TSA endpoint to sign my jars.

- when I use this TSA http://tsa.starfieldtech.com the application run fine with JRE6,8
- when I use this TSA http://services.globaltrustfinder.com/adss/tsa the application runs only with JRE8

From this resource http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/jarsigner.html I read
*To generate the time stamp, jarsigner communicates with the TSA with the Time-Stamp Protocol (TSP) defined in RFC 3161. When successful, the time stamp token returned by the TSA is stored with the signature in the signature block file.*

Someone can give more insight about this problem? In particular I don't want to be forced to use a particular TSA.
Why there are this differences between TSA?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I my case the applet really had unsigned entry in META-INF folder. )
One way to fix that would be to re-sign it.
But in java 8 self-signed applets were [demoted](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/jcp_security.xml) to almost the same level as unsigned ones. And the applet didn't required any additional privileges.
So it was sufficient to just [un-sign](https://kbdeveloper.qoppa.com/?p=3788) it and [add to trusted sites list](https://superuser.com/questions/715659/allowing-unsigned-java-applications-on-all-sites).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when compiling on my **linux** maschine (with JDK 6 U45).
But I got this error **only** when I also tried to **start** the signed application with Java 6 U45.

When I try to start the application with a **newer** Java-Version (e.g Java 8) it was OK all the time, with no error message.

When I used a **windows** maschine to compile the project (also with 6 Update 45), it strangely works also when I use Java 6 U45 to start.

Just my 2 cents....
Cheers!