# Unable to launch application : JNLP error

Tags: java, java-web-start, jnlp

I found answer to this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17923635/found-unsigned-entry-in-resource)!

However, I tried enabling java caching by checking “Keep temporary files on my computer.”
But I still get the exception:

```
com.sun.deploy.net.JARSigningException: Found unsigned entry in resource: http://localhost:8080/<context-root>/client/servlet-api.jar
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.getCommonCodeSignersForJar(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.SigningInfo.check(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResourcesHelper(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.security.JNLPSignedResourcesHelper.checkSignedResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareAllResources(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: Why doies the client side code need `servlet-api.jar`?  Is that Jar digitally signed?

Comment: Actually, client is my folder name. Sorry about that. No it is not signed but neither of the other jars are signed.

Comment: *"No it is not signed.."*  All code for any JWS launched app. needs to be digitally signed!

Comment: How do I sign a jnlp jar?

Comment: *"How do I sign a jnlp jar?"*  Exactly the same way that you would [sign a Jar file](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+do+I+sign+a+jar%3F).
Oh, and please don't mistake SO for a help desk.  Do some research before asking questions.